# Prove that every set formed by polynomials of different degrees is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How to prove that every set formed by polynomials of different degrees is linearly independent.

My problem is in how to make a general set of polynomials of different degrees.

Comment: You don't generate them, you are given them as part of the problem. Do you perhaps mean represent them?

Comment: Proof by contradiction might be a good choice.

Comment: Yes, that was actually what I was trying to ask. However the first answer was the most helpful in proving what I wanted, showing that there is no need to write each polynomial of the set the way I wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an argument along the following lines:

- Let $A={f_1,...,f_n}$ be a set of polynomials, each of which has a different degree. Suppose that they are arranged in order so $f_1$ has the lowest degree, and $f_n$  the higest.
- Assume that they are not linearly indepedant. Then we can find constants which are not all zero such that $$c_1 f_1+...c_n f_n=0.$$
- what must $c_n $ be? Then what must $c_{n-1} $ be? Why does this lead to a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial of finite degree $n$ can be written as $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ and can be represented as tupel of coefficients $(a_0, a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$. Polynomials of lesser degrees could be embedded in that $n+1$-dimensional vector space. The standard base would consist of the monomials $x^k$. Different degrees would mean different highest order monomials and thus linear independence.

Answer (score 0):

I would order them in increasing degree.  Then, if $\langle S \rangle$ denotes the subspace generated by a subset $S$, I would use the following fact:

**FACT:**  If $u_1, \ldots , u_r$ are linearly independent and $u_{r+1}$ does not belong to $\langle u_1, \ldots, u_r\rangle$, then $u_1, \ldots , u_{r+1}$ are linearly independent.

This follows from considering a linear combination which yields $0$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^{r+1} \lambda_i u_i=0,$ and studying the cases $\lambda_{r+1}\neq 0$ and $\lambda_{r+1}=0$ separately.

Applying the above to our collection of polynomials with increasing degrees, the result follows.