# Proof that S is a subset of R[x] and it is linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof that if $S$ is a finite subset of elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and each element of $S$ is a polynomial with different degree from the other elements, then $S$ is linearly independent.

I have been struggling with this. I once read a document which stated that if $S$ contains the constant function which is equal to 0, then $S$ is not linearly independent.

Comment: Vocabulary comment: you should replace 1) "limited cardinalities" by "finite" and 2) "order" (of a polynomial) by "degree".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716570/prove-that-every-set-formed-by-polynomials-of-different-degrees-is-linearly-inde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way: you can consider the basis $B=\{x^n,x^{n-1},\ldots,x,1\}$ on $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ where $n$ is the maximum degree of the elemente of $S$. Then, the matrix $M$ whose rows are the coordinates of the elements of $S$ with respect to $B$, trivially satisfies $\text{rank }(M)=\# S.$

Edited. **@Hyunna:** I've considered the well known isomorphism between vectors an coordinates when a basis is fixed. Here you can find different alternatives:

[Prove that every set formed by polynomials of different degrees is linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716570/prove-that-every-set-formed-by-polynomials-of-different-degrees-is-linearly-inde)

Comment: Thank, but i dont know that we can form those elements of S into a matrix,..they 're polynomials...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your problem is direct application of following simple lemma:

**Lemma:** Recall that if $S$ is a subset of some vector spave $V$ and $v$ is an element of $V$ such that $v \notin$ span$(S)$ Then $S \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent.

Can you see how to complete your question using the hint?

Answer (score 1):

- Suppose there exists a linear dependence between some members of $S$, i.e. $\exists a_i\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}, p_i\in S$ such that $\sum_i a_ip_i=0$.
- Then, by the distinctness of degrees of the elements of $S$, one of these $p_i$ has uniquely highest degree, i.e. $\exists i^*$ such that $\deg p_{i^*}>\deg p_i$ for all $i\neq i^*$.
- Then it is plain to see that $\sum_i a_ip_i$ is a polynomial of degree exactly $\deg p_{i^*}$, and thus is nonzero.
- This gives a contradiction, and  hence, no such linear dependence exists, i.e.our set is linearly independent.

Comment: But do you know why if there exists an element which is a constant function equal to 0 then S is not linearly independent??

Comment: I think the question only makes sense if you assume no members of $S$ are $0$, otherwise there's trivially a linear dependence ($1\cdot 0 = 0$). This is somewhat compatible with the proof given, as the "degree" of the polynomial $0$ is often understood to be $-\infty$ (formally at least).